# what does sched_feat macro in scheduler mean

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

The following macro is defined in `./kernel/sched/sched.h`

```
#define sched_feat(x) (static_branch_##x(&sched_feat_keys[__SCHED_FEAT_##x]))
#else /* !(SCHED_DEBUG && HAVE_JUMP_LABEL) */
#define sched_feat(x) (sysctl_sched_features & (1UL << __SCHED_FEAT_##x))
#endif /* SCHED_DEBUG && HAVE_JUMP_LABEL */
```

I am unable to understand what role does it play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sched_feat()` macro is used in scheduler code to test if a certain scheduler feature is enabled.  For example, in `kernel/sched/core.c`, there is a snippet of code

```
int mutex_spin_on_owner(struct mutex *lock, struct task_struct *owner)
{
        if (!sched_feat(OWNER_SPIN))
                return 0;
```

which is testing whether the "spin-wait on mutex acquisition if the mutex owner is running" feature is set.  You can see the full list of scheduler features in `kernel/sched/features.h` but a short summary is that they are tunables settable at runtime without rebuilding the kernel through `/sys/kernel/debug/sched_features`.

For example if you have not changed the default settings on your system, you will see "OWNER_SPIN" in your `/sys/kernel/debug/sched_features`, which means the `!sched_feat(OWNER_SPIN)` in the snippet above will evaluate to false and the scheduler code will continue on into the rest of the code in `mutex_spin_on_owner()`.

The reason that the macro definition you partially copied is more complicated than you might expect is that it uses the [jump labels](https://lwn.net/Articles/436041/) feature when available and needed to eliminate the overhead of these conditional tests in frequently run scheduler code paths.  (The jump label version is only used when `HAVE_JUMP_LABEL` is set in the config, for obvious reasons, and when `SCHED_DEBUG` is set because otherwise the scheduler feature bits can't change at runtime)  You can follow the link above to lwn.net for more details, but in a nutshell jump labels are a way to use runtime binary patching to make conditional tests of flags much cheaper at the cost of making changing the flags much more expensive.

You can also look at the [scheduler commit that introduced jump label use](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=f8b6d1cc7dc15cf3de538b864eefaedad7a84d85) to see how the code used to be a bit simpler but not quite as efficient.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any good point where I can read implementation specific details about kernel. It would be of great help.